# Two finger scroll only when mouse not clicked

Tags: touchpad

I want to do BOTH of the following things using my touchpad:

1. Two finger scroll. I know how to enable it and it works pretty well.
2. Click and resize. So on e.g. google docs or Libreoffice I can click on an object, then while holding down the clicker, resize the object.

The issue is that #2 activates the two finger scroll. Can I somehow disable two finger scroll if and only if my mouse button is held down?

I'm running 16.04.
xinput output:

```
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DELL0741:00 06CB:7E7E Touchpad            id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate           id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel Virtual Button driver               id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Cheers!

Comment: What is the output of `xinput list`

Comment: I'd recommend installing latest libinput *(I'm assuming it wasn't yet default in 16.04)*, and then if it's still not working, [report a bug](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/issues).

Comment: i have tested on my Toshiba laptop it is working fine. i could click and hold the left button and resize the selected object. two finger scrolling is working fine on the plain area of touch pad.

Comment: @Thornkey when you press the left mouse button is it working same like just tapping?

Comment: hmm @PRATAP now that you mention it i can't seem to reproduce it on demand ;-; It happened again when i was screenshotting a PDF

Comment: also yes it works the same as tapping

Comment: @Thronkey as Hi-Angel commented, have you installed latest libinput? i have latest libinput and my touchpad is doing what you asked.

Comment: @Thronkey on the normal webpage, if you click and hold the left mouse button with one finger and scroll up & down with other finger whats happening?

Comment: ok i got it - so if i double TAP and drag, then it scrolls, but if I CLICK and drag, then it doesn't scroll. I would like double tap to work like clicking.

Comment: I installed libinput and it doesnt seem to change much